# crawling a page and being recognize as a robot

Tags: web-crawler, httpwebrequest

I am trying to crawl through some sites. When trying to read from some of them I get a broken page with an header saying I am recognize as a robot.
This is my code:

```
 HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);           

 //req.Timeout = 5000;
 req.UserAgent = ProxiesExtension.GetRandomUserAgent();
 //request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.121 Safari/535.2";
 req.Method = "GET";
 //request.ContentType = "application/json";
 req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
 //request.Accept = accept ?? @"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8";
 // request.Headers["Accept-Encoding"] = "gzip, deflate, sdch";
 req.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8");
```

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

Your probably trying to request to many pages to fast from the same ip address. You will likely need to be more "polite". A few things to try...

1) respect the robots.txt file

2) wait 10-30 seconds in between requests

3) distribute your requests over multiple proxies

Try using [Abot](https://github.com/sjdirect/abot) which is a ready made c# web crawler that handles #1 & #2 out of the box. You can handle #3 with something like [this](https://github.com/mnta/Abot.MultiProxyPoliteWebCrawler).